# OpenLayers 3 set custom extent for ImageCanvas layer

Tags: javascript, canvas, openlayers-3

Is it possible in OpenLayers 3 to set a custom extent for an Image layer that uses ImageCanvas as its source? It seems that by default, when using ImageCanvas, OL creates a layer with extent equal to the current view extent plus half, and updates the extent on every render. Setting an extent for the Image layer somehow breaks the ImageCanvas source, which is never created (canvasFunction is never called).

I'm drawing images with a fixed location to the canvas that I would like to appear when the map pans over their extent (i.e. during a pan animation). As it stands, the Image layer's extent won't be updated until a moveend event, so the canvas sits in its old position during the entirety of the pan. It seems it's impossible to force a render/update of the canvas layer during a pan operation, but I figured if it's possible to set a larger extent for the Image layer that covers all the images I want to draw, that won't be a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at ol.source.ImageCanvas in the OL3 API documentation and unmark the "stable only" in uppr right corner. you will see that you can make a canvasFunction, which can be used to manipulate the extent. Maybe that could be a help? I have never used this function by my self.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I can tell, the renderer passes the current extent of the canvas layer to the canvasFunction (which is always equal to the current view extent plus half). It can't be manipulated.